# IndexedDB not working in jsFiddle on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, jsfiddle, indexeddb

Can anybody tell my why IndexedDB is ***not*** working inside [this](http://jsfiddle.net/s4e92yrr/) jsFiddle on Firefox (while it does work on Chrome) ?

It should alert '[object IDBFactory]'.

When I try the same code in the Firebug console, it does work, but NOT in this fiddle!

The code :

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB
                     || window.webkitIndexedDB
                     || window.mozIndexedDB;

alert(window.indexedDB);
```